# Почему plurals для слова автомобиль отрабатывают некорректно?

Tags: android

Есть вот такие `plurals`, который лежит в файле строк:

```
<plurals name="cars">
        <item quantity="zero">%d автомобилей</item>
        <item quantity="one">%d автомобиль</item>
        <item quantity="two">%d автомобиля</item>
        <item quantity="few">%d автомобиля</item>
        <item quantity="many">%d автомобилей</item>
        <item quantity="other">%d автомобилей</item>
    </plurals>
```

Получаю строку вот так:

```
resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.cars, 2, 2)
```

Приходит - 2 автомобилей (`other`).

Если не прописать `other` приложение падает:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Plural resource ID #0x7f110001 quantity=2 item=other

Comment: Попробуйте оставить только `one, few, many` и `other` если будет падать.

Comment: Может вы добавили этот ресурс не в русскую локаль? Дефолтная локаль - английская и у неё нет особых правил для `2,3,4`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы создаете plurals в values/strings.xml, то будут применяться правила склонения для языка, который установлен в системе. Например, если у вас в телефоне (или эмуляторе) установлен русский язык, то будут работать правила:

- one(1,21,31..),
- few(2-4,22-24,...),
- many (0,5-20,25-30,...)

Если английский, то:

- one (1)
- other (0, >1)

Для французского:

- one (0,1)
- other (>1)

Таким образом в values/strings.xml plurals будут зависеть от языка системы и абсолютно красиво не будет, пока вы не сделаете локализацию для всех языков.

Самый простой вариант - это явно переключать локаль на русский язык внутри приложения:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(updateLocale(base));
        applyOverrideConfiguration(base.getResources().getConfiguration()); // тут может бросить IllegalStateException, на всякий отловить
    }

    private static Context updateLocale(Context context){
        Locale ruLocale = new Locale("ru");
        Locale.setDefault(ruLocale);

        Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        configuration.setLocale(ruLocale);
        configuration.setLayoutDirection(ruLocale);

        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
    }
}
```

При данном подходе отдельные ресурсы для других языков не нужны, в т.ч. для русского. Достаточно values/strings.xml.

Ну и дальше развить данную мысль, когда и если все-таки появится частичная локализация, то явно перекидывать локаль с неизвестной, например в en или в ru. Тогда все ресурсы, в частности plurals будут работать так, как вы ожидаете, а не так как android решит.