# Числительные не работают правильно в android

Tags: android, kotlin

Делаю склонения согласно [примеру](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/plurals.php):

`strings.xml`

```
    <plurals name="product_plurals">
        <item quantity="zero">%1$d товаров на сумму</item>
        <item quantity="one">%1$d товар на сумму</item>
        <item quantity="two">%1$d товара на сумму</item>
        <item quantity="few">%1$d товара на сумму</item>
        <item quantity="many">%1$d товаров на сумму</item>
        <item quantity="other">%1$d товаров на сумму</item>
    </plurals>
```

вывожу в лог

```kotlin
        for (i in 0..33) {
            val testPlural = this.resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.product_plurals, i, i)
            Log.i("Plurals", " $testPlural")
        }
```

корректно отрабатывает только для 1го

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

где может быть ошибка?

Comment: Вы неправильно скопировали код примера, где у вас определяются в вашем коде zero, one и так далее?

Comment: в файле strings.xml всё у меня правильно, я уже нашёл в чём причина, надо установить ru локаль

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1335698